# C# combining single value enum with flags enum

Tags: c#, enums

I would like to use a flags enum as a filterset to filter on a single value enum.

When I use one flags enum to provide both, I have two objections:

- The naming convention states than a flags enum is plural, and a single item enum not;
- I would like the filter/flags enum to have values for "none" and "all", but these are not valid values when not used as a filter;

An example stating my intention (but which does not run properly due to type incompatibility between the two enums)

```
    enum Material
    {
        wood,
        metal,
        plastic
    }

    [Flags]
    enum Materials
    {
        none = 0,
        wood = 1,
        metal = 2,
        plastic = 4,
        all = 7
    }

    var filter = Materials.all;

    foreach (article in articles.Where(a => Filter.HasFlag(a.FinishMaterial))
        ...
```

As mentioned, this example does not do what I want.
It feels not OK to only use the Materials enum because none and all are not valid values for an article finish.

I could use some casting to int to translate between both enums. But there should be a more elegant, non cluttered way to do this, right?

[edit after answer from Dennis]
I actually did think about using a collection as a filter. Also it feels heavy weight, requires more code,  while using enums is lightweight. However, when is doesn't do the job I have no user for it, lightweigt/elegant or not...

[edit after marking as ansered]
Thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most optimal way is to use `int` conversions rather than `Enum.Parse`. To resolve your problem with `HasFlag` you can create an extension method. Below is the code with test

```
[TestClass]
public class MaterialsTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Contains_wroks_as_expected()
    {
        var filter = Materials.all;
        Assert.IsTrue(filter.Contains(Material.metal));
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this Materials filter, Material material)
    {
        var valueToFilter = (Materials)(int)(material);
        return filter.HasFlag(valueToFilter);
    }
}

public enum Material
{
    wood = 1,
    metal = 2,
    plastic = 4
}

[Flags]
public enum Materials
{
    none = 0,
    wood = 1,
    metal = 2,
    plastic = 4,
    all = 7
}
```

Comment: This is a nice lightweight and elegant way of solving this!

Answer (score 1):

IMO, using collection to hold the filter is much easier and readable, than manipulating flags:

```
// This is equivalent of "var filter = Materials.all";
// an empty collection is equivalent of "Materials.None"
var filter = (Material[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Material));
// use next line, if you need to modify the filter:
// var filter = ((Material[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Material))).ToList();

foreach (article in articles.Where(a => filter.Contains(a.FinishMaterial)))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a 2 solutions:

First:

```
Material value = (Material)Enum.Parse(typeof (Material), Materials.wood.ToString());
```

*I.e. convert enums*

Second: use only Materials enum. Not clear but simple.